# The Facebook login popup window position

Tags: javascript, popup, position, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am working with the Facebook Login API ( FB.login ) where I'm using some custom logic to authorize an user into my app. It works fine but I have some pesky issue. When the user clicks on the Facebook Login button the Facebook popup appears at the right side of a screen.

I have been tried to find some solution in the FB Api docs since yesterday but I haven't found anything.

This window appears like different browser window so I can't change it's position via js/css unfortunately.

Thanks for any help!

P.S. Here is the code (it's a standard FB login API)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });
    } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
});
```

Comment: hard to help without an example...please add your url or at least a screenshot

Comment: It's the standard Facebook code, nothing special. P.S. I have added it already into the post.

Comment: ok, but i have used that code a lot of times already and never had that problem. it always pops up centered. maybe i am not sure what you want to ask, so at least a screenshot would be good.